# Formating a table from a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv

I'm trying to make a table from data from a CSV file using only the CSV module. Could anyone tell me what should I do to display the '|' at the end of every row(just after the last element in the row)?
Here's what I have so far:

```
def display_playlist( filename ):

     if filename.endswith('.csv')==False: #check if it ends with CSV extension
         filename = filename + ('.csv') #adding .csv if given without .csv extension
     max_element_length=0
     #aligning columns to the longest elements
     for row in get_datalist_from_csv( filename ):
         for element in row:
             if len(element)>max_element_length:
                 max_element_length=len(element)
        # print(max_element_length)                
     #return max_element_length

     print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
     for row in get_datalist_from_csv( filename ):
         for element in row:
             print('| ', end='')
             if (len(element)<=4 and element.isdigit==True):
                 print(pad_to_length(element,4), end=' |')  #trying to get '|' at the end[enter image description here][1]
             else:
                 print(pad_to_length(element, max_element_length), end=' ')

         print('\n')
     print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------')

## Read data from a csv format file
def get_datalist_from_csv( filename ):
    ## Create a 'file object' f, for accessing the file: 
    with open( filename ) as f:  
         reader = csv.reader(f)     # create a 'csv reader' from the file object
         datalist = list( reader )  # create a list from the reader 
    return datalist # we have a list of lists

## For aligning table columns
## It adds spaces to the end of a string to make it up to length n.
def pad_to_length( string, n):
    return string + " "* (n-len(string)) ## s*n gives empty string for n<1
```

The image I get for now is:

---

| Track                | Artist               | Album                | Time

| Computer Love        | Kraftwerk            | Computer World       | 7:15

| Paranoid Android     | Radiohead            | OK Computer          | 6:27

| Computer Age         | Neil Young           | Trans                | 5:24

| Digital              | Joy Division         | Still                | 2:50

| Silver Machine       | Hawkwind             | Roadhawks            | 4:39

| Start the Simulator  | A-Ha                 | Foot of the Mountain | 5:11

| Internet Connection  | M.I.A.               | MAYA                 | 2:56

| Deep Blue            | Arcade Fire          | The Suburbs          | 4:29

| I Will Derive!       | MindofMatthew        | You Tube             | 3:17

| Lobachevsky          | Tom Lehrer           | You Tube             | 3:04

---

Comment: Can't you just change your `print('\n')` to `print('|\n')` near the end of your `print` loop?

Comment: That makes '|' show at the very end of the string (e.x. | 3:17          |) and I want it to be displayed right after (| 3:17 |)

Comment: Nevermind, I just realised what I should do